# Can I install IIS7 on a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

Can I install IIS7 on a Windows 2003 Serer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, IIS7 is for Windows Server 2008 and Vista. You can however install the IIS7 Manager on a XP client for example.

Comment: See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609

Answer (score 0):

No.  pauska's answer is correct.

This question was also asked and answered [here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1158749/1908275.aspx#1908275).